# What is the relationship between Subaru and Rem after he confesses his feeling in episode 25?

Tags: re-zero

After the end of episode 25, Subaru confesses his feeling for

> Emilia.

So, are Subaru and Rem just friends now? Or does Rem or Subaru have any feeling for the other?

Comment: Rem confessed her feelings to Subaru, thought I can't remember in which episode. Subaru answers that he does love Emilia and not Rem.

Comment: Yes Subaru has always maintained that he loves Emilia , rem is actually the one who falls in love with  Subaru. And would this question count as opinion based?

Comment: No, this question is not opinion-based as feelings between the said characters are actually described through the anime. We may also have more details coming from the Light Novel, e.g the original content of re:zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[On the re:zero wiki description of the episode 18](http://rezero.wikia.com/wiki/Re:Zero_Episode_18), it is said :

> Listening on, **Rem listed on the reasons why she loves him**. From the way he brushed her hair, held her hand, and walked together, she gently continued the daily things about him that she adored. As Subaru asked why, Rem told him that listening to him say he hated himself made her want to tell him all of the wonderful things she knows about him. Subaru retorted back that his behavior was phony, as he knows himself best. Finally raising her voice, Rem retorted tearfully that if all he understood was himself, then he knows nothing about how she views him. To her, he is a hero who saved her by saying the words that melted her frozen heart and allowed her to move on from her past. With the acknowledgement that someone else believes in him and is willing to support him, Subaru slowly regained his resolve. In the process, **Subaru confessed that he loves Emilia, with his goal being able to see her smile. Rem joked that it was cruel of him to ask of this from a girl he just rejected.**

So it is clearly stated that Rem loves Subaru and that Subaru rejected Rem as he loves Emilia, but they are still friends.

Comment: watched episode 18 again ..

Answer (score 3):

If you consider just the anime then they can be classified as just friends but it's actually more complicated than that.
Minor web novel spoilers ahead:

> In the web novel we see that Subaru holds both Rem as well as Emilia in his heart and as far as how the love interest will be handled I haven't gotten that ahead in the novel yet. In the arc immediately following the end of anime Subaru clearly states that he loves both Emilia as well as Rem in multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

Episode 21 kinda hints that there's still feelings between the two when you see their little moment they share at the end of the episode and Subaru asking Rem to stay by his side even though he said he loved Emilia. Not to mention that he tells Crusch that he already has a #1 and #2 in his heart with the second spot obviously being for Rem, showing that he views Rem as more than just a friend to him (in the light novel, Rem fakes her death to trick Subaru into confessing his true feelings for her)

The light novel makes it more obvious that they have feelings for each other and Arc's 4-6 take place after the events of the anime. Subaru actually admits to having feelings for both Emilia and Rem and agrees to make Rem his second wife under the condition that Emilia agrees to it.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously Subaru loves Emilia, but that doesn't mean he don't like Rem. In the episode when Subaru comes back to life, before the confession, after he refers to "my beautiful Rem", I understand that Emilia was the first girl he met, but I know based on watching the episode that he loves Emilia a little more than Rem, and if he'd never made that promise to Emilia, he would have probably picked Rem.